# How to split an XML API response between Dict and List

Tags: xml, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following XML response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<export_response xmlns:xsd="" xmlns:xsi="" xmlns="">
  <success>true</success>
  <row_count>2</row_count>
  <offers>
    <offer>
      <offer_id>336</offer_id>
      <offer_name>Home Page Flagship Product</offer_name>
      <advertiser>
        <advertiser_id xmlns="API:id_name_store">61</advertiser_id>
        <advertiser_name xmlns="API:id_name_store">bradvertiser</advertiser_name>
      </advertiser>
      <vertical>
        <vertical_id xmlns="API:id_name_store">87</vertical_id>
        <vertical_name xmlns="API:id_name_store">DTC Ecom</vertical_name>
      </vertical>
      <offer_type>
        <offer_type_id xmlns="API:id_name_store">3</offer_type_id>
        <offer_type_name xmlns="API:id_name_store">3rd Party</offer_type_name>
      </offer_type>
      <offer_status>
        <offer_status_id xmlns="API:id_name_store">1</offer_status_id>
        <offer_status_name xmlns="API:id_name_store">Public</offer_status_name>
      </offer_status>
      <hidden>false</hidden>
    </offer>
    <offer>
      <offer_id>337</offer_id>
      <offer_name>Complimentary Product</offer_name>
      <advertiser>
        <advertiser_id xmlns="API:id_name_store">61</advertiser_id>
        <advertiser_name xmlns="API:id_name_store">bradvertiser</advertiser_name>
      </advertiser>
      <vertical>
        <vertical_id xmlns="API:id_name_store">87</vertical_id>
        <vertical_name xmlns="API:id_name_store">DTC Ecom</vertical_name>
      </vertical>
      <offer_type>
        <offer_type_id xmlns="API:id_name_store">3</offer_type_id>
        <offer_type_name xmlns="API:id_name_store">3rd Party</offer_type_name>
      </offer_type>
      <offer_status>
        <offer_status_id xmlns="API:id_name_store">1</offer_status_id>
        <offer_status_name xmlns="API:id_name_store">Public</offer_status_name>
      </offer_status>
      <hidden>false</hidden>
    </offer>
  </offers>
<export_response>
```

Here is my block of code:

```
import requests
import json
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



addOfferValues = []
    for data in csv_reader:
        url = ""
        params = {"api_key":"",
                "offer_name":"",
                "offer_id":data['Offer ID'],
                "advertiser_id":data['Advertiser ID'],
                "vertical_id":data['Vertical ID'],
                "offer_type_id":"0",
                "media_type_id":"0",
                "tag_id":"0",
                "start_at_row":"0",
                "row_limit":"0",
                "sort_field":"offer_name",
                "sort_descending":"TRUE",
                "offer_status_id":"0"}

        req = requests.get(url, params=params)
        response = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')

        hidden = response.find('hidden').string
        hidden = 'on' if hidden == 'true' else 'off'

        addOfferParams = {"api_key":"",
                    "offer_id":"0",
                    "advertiser_id":response.find('advertiser_id').string,
                    "vertical_id":response.find('vertical_id').string,
                    "offer_name":response.find('offer_name').string,
                    "third_party_name":"",
                    "hidden":hidden,
                    "offer_status_id":response.find('offer_status_id').string,
                    "offer_type_id":response.find('offer_type_id').string}
        addOfferValues.append(addOfferParams)
        addOfferReq = requests.get('https://cs1', params=addOfferParams)
```

My goal is to capture the first offer:

```
<offer>
      <offer_id>336</offer_id>
      <offer_name>Home Page Flagship Product</offer_name>
      <advertiser>
        <advertiser_id xmlns="API:id_name_store">61</advertiser_id>
        <advertiser_name xmlns="API:id_name_store">bradvertiser</advertiser_name>
      </advertiser>
      <vertical>
        <vertical_id xmlns="API:id_name_store">87</vertical_id>
        <vertical_name xmlns="API:id_name_store">DTC Ecom</vertical_name>
      </vertical>
      <offer_type>
        <offer_type_id xmlns="API:id_name_store">3</offer_type_id>
        <offer_type_name xmlns="API:id_name_store">3rd Party</offer_type_name>
      </offer_type>
      <offer_status>
        <offer_status_id xmlns="API:id_name_store">1</offer_status_id>
        <offer_status_name xmlns="API:id_name_store">Public</offer_status_name>
      </offer_status>
      <hidden>false</hidden>
    </offer>
```

and store in my addOfferParams Dict which I have done successfully. If the row_count is greater than 1 I want the second offer data or any additional offers to be stored in my addOfferValues List. I will then make a second request with those data points. I would appreciate any advice here as ran into a noob roadblock. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am reading in from a file but it shows the principle of looping over all the offer rows and adding to the final list. I use `soup` to refer to the `soup` object rather than `response` as I find that less confusing.

You can then loop the final list making your requests.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

addOfferValues = []

with open(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.xml', encoding="utf8") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "lxml")

    hidden = soup.find('hidden').string
    hidden = 'on' if hidden == 'true' else 'off' # assuming this is correct and as wanted 

    for offer in soup.select('offer'):
        addOfferParams = {"api_key":"",
                        "offer_id": offer.select_one('offer_id').text, # I had added. Did you wish to exclude?
                        "advertiser_id": offer.select_one('advertiser_id').text,
                        "vertical_id": offer.select_one('vertical_id').text,
                        "offer_name": offer.select_one('offer_name').text,
                        "third_party_name":"",
                        "hidden":hidden,
                        "offer_status_id": offer.select_one('offer_status_id').text,   # I had added. Did you wish to exclude?
                        "offer_type_id":  offer.select_one('offer_type_id').text} 
        addOfferValues.append(addOfferParams)

print(addOfferValues)

#loop final list making requests with params
```

---

Output:

[image]

Comment: Dd you try this?